# Want to get the data from a nested mongodb from R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

My mongodb is looking like this :

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("5751749723be8328848af30e"),
"mem_id" : 1.0,
"mem_name" : "Member1",
"home" : "8001234567",
"mobile" : "8771231234",
"email" : "jd@example.com",
"mem_create_date" : ISODate("2016-06-03T12:14:15.642Z"),
"paymethod" : {
    "pm_id" : "99991",
    "pm_name" : "FA11",
    "pm_create_Date" : ISODate("2013-12-09T21:05:00.000Z"),
    "routing_no" : "075000051"
},
"payee" : {
    "pae_id" : "88881",
    "pae_name" : "Payee1",
    "home" : "800-123-45671",
    "mobile" : "877-123-12341",
    "email" : "jd@example.com",
    "act_no" : "0213654781",
    "pae_create_date" : ISODate("2013-12-09T21:05:00.000Z"),
    "payment" : {
        "pmt_id" : "66661",
        "pmt_amt" : "71",
        "pmt_create_date" : ISODate("2013-12-09T21:05:00.000Z"),
        "pmt_type" : "check"
    }
}
```

}

I need to get these values with the help of mongolite and show them in a plot/graph with R shiny web app. 
I could not find any example with nested mongodb on net. And whenever i am trying to read the data i am getting the below err :

```
error in if (inherits(x j dataframe ) && ncol(xj) 1l) x j - as.matrix(x j )
```

Can anyone please help/guide me here. I am a java developer but i am new to R language. 
Thanks.

Comment: The below is my code +
loadData <- function(qry){
  mong <- mongo(..)
  df <- mong$find('{"paymethod.pm_name":"FA11","paymethod.routing_no":"075000051"}', fields = '{"_id":0, "paymethod.pm_name":1}')
  return(df)
}shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  qryResults <- reactive({
    region <- list(region = input$si_region)
    qry <- paste0('{"mem_name":1,"Member1":1}', fields = '{"_id":0, "mem_name":1}')
    df <- loadData(qry)
    return(df)
  })
  output$qry_results <- renderDataTable({
    qryResults()
  })
  output$text1 <- renderText(nrow(qryResults()))
 })